# Filtering bad words from a web browser in vb.net

Tags: .net, visual-studio, filtering, webbrowser-control

I want to develop a system that will filter bad words from a browser and replace it with a (*) .
The concept is the web browser will inserted into a windows form and inside the form all text from the web browser will be read and if words detected from our database it will automatically replaced with a character (***)

Comment: OK, so you'll probably have to look for one of the events on the WebBrowser control (DocumentCompleted?) and add a handler to that, and then read out and edit all of the content in that handler. Or it might be possible to do some or all of this by injecting JavaScript into the page. Which parts do you need help with specifically?

Comment: Specifically on how to replace the words in a web browser (list of words from our database) .